# Integrating Erlang with C++

Tags: c++, erlang

What interfaces exist to tie Erlang with C++?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- [Native implemented functions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html): available in the latest Erlang/OTP version, allows you to implement any of your functions in C.
- [Port drivers](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html): you can link a C code to the Erlang VM, and access it using port_command.
- C Nodes: With the [ei](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ei.html) library you can mimic a VM and talk to your Erlang VMs using the Erlang distribution format.

Comment: NFI are still experimental... but I am hopeful and eagerly awaiting a stable interface for these!

Comment: True, they are experimental, but having a "fallback" Erlang function implementation is so nice that it even worth changing your C code for every upcoming release :)

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I know for interfacing Erlang with **C++ directly is [EPAPI](http://epapi.googlecode.com/)**. Of course it relies on the tried and tested **C `erl_interface`** that comes standard with the Erlang distribution.

Comment: EPAPI is at version 0.7 so I presume that one is still experimental as well :o)

Comment: It is very stable nonetheless :-)

Answer (score 0):

To Zed's excellent answer, I would add `open_port()`.  It lets you start an external program and communicate with it from Erlang using its standard in and out.  You can use it like Unix pipes by giving the {line, L} option, or there's also the length-prefixed {packet, N} option which I find to be safer and more efficient.

The advantage of this over NIFs and port drivers is that your Erlang code is totally insulated from the C code.  The C program can smash its own stack, double-free blocks of memory, enter an infinite loop, whatever.  None of this stops your Erlang code.  At worst, you close the Erlang port and re-open it if things go pear-shaped.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone interested in the erlang/C++ integration aspect, may also want to check out this article: [Rewriting Playdar: C++ to Erlang, massive savings](http://www.metabrew.com/article/rewriting-playdar-c-to-erlang-massive-savings):

> I’ve heard many anecdotes and claims about how many lines of code are saved when you write in Erlang instead of [C++/other language]. I’m happy to report that I now have first-hand experience and some data to share.
>
> I initially wrote Playdar in C++ (using Boost and Asio libraries), starting back in February this year. I was fortunate to be working with some experienced developers who helped me come to terms with C++. There were three of us hacking on it regularly up until a few months ago, and despite being relatively new to C++, I’ll say that we ended up with a well designed and robust codebase, all things considered.

Comment: They started having written 8,035 lines of code, and a few weeks later they'd written 10,067 lines of code, 80% of which they threw away, had added no new functionality in the process, this is a saving?  Must be an open source thing, as there's no way a business would justify that. (writing it in Erlang to start with would be a different matter)

Comment: It's a major savings when it comes to reducing future technical debt. Fewer lines of code = easier to maintain, debug, and add new features later.