# State of Erlang and C/C++ integration?

Tags: c++, c, erlang, erlang-ports

If we check the official [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/introduction.html) we can find various ways of interfacing Erlang and C/C++. A similar question was asked here in [2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811516/integrating-erlang-with-c) and I would like to know how the things changed since then.

Is there any mature stable library that does all the dirty work of implementing binary protocols between Erlang and C? Is it `ei` or `erl_interface` and what is the [difference](http://somethingsimilar.com/2007/09/02/erl_interface-is-deprecated-and-i-hate-the-erlang-docs/) between them?

I mean this seems to be a quite common problem and I hope that someone has successfully solved it already and there is no need to write your own Erlang Port Driver anymore, since most of it is generic code.

P.S. I have also found this library: [EPAPI](http://epapi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/package/docs/html/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing have changed significantly since 2009, the top answer from the question you linked is still correct.

NIFs became less experimental starting from R14 and are actively used in some projects, but they are still incompatible with HiPE compiler (native flag to compile).