# Are there any support vector machine modules available for Erlang?

Tags: erlang, libraries, svm, libsvm

Are there any Erlang compatible SVM implementations available, or Erlang bindings that can be used with the [libsvm library](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/)? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I could not find any implementation of SVM in Erlang. You may have to write your own interfacing with it. There are several ways to do it.
You can check these in [Erlang Interoperability Tutorial](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/overview.html)

1. [NIF Driver](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html)
2. [Port Driver](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html)
3. Ports
4. Erl interface
5. C nodes

You can also check stackoverflow link [Integrating Erlang with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811516/integrating-erlang-with-c).

Comment: "The libsvm library is written in Python" That's not true, libsvm is written in C with bindings for several languages. Unfortunately Erlang is not one of those