# Running C code in erlang

Tags: c, erlang

How to run c code in Erlang? Please explain with simple example.
Basically I am trying to post data on a server with this.I will trigger the C code through Erlang and then this C code will post data to server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run C Code Block in Erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525457/run-c-code-block-in-erlang)

Comment: http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0007.html

Answer (score 2):

This question comes back very often: [one of the best answers is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1811973/912225)

I would also add [ports](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html) to the mix. Do not confuse them with port drivers: [ports vs port drivers](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html)

For your use case ports should be the best option. Nifs can crash Erlang VM, so they are only for optimizing critical code. Port drivers have similar problems. C nodes mimic Erlang VM and I haven't seen good use case for them yet.

Ports are just normal OS processes with a protocol used to communicate with Erlang VM. This is usually the default way to go, when you want to call some C code from Erlang.